# JSON Unmarshal struct case-sensitively

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Is there any way to make json.Unmarshal *not* accept a case-insensitive match? I receive a JSON with tags such as "e" and "E" and would like to unmarshal the object with tag "e" but ignore the one with "E". Right now the only solution I found was to define a struct containing both tags and then to simply ignore tag "E",  but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

From the official doc:

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match.

Comment: forking and editing decode.go to prevent case insensitive matching is an option, too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something currently supported by the standard json library.

According to https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

> Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match

There is no way to turn this behaviour off.

Comment: Is there an alternative library which is similar to the std lib but with the option to have strict case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to add a field with special type, which ignores jsonon unmarshalling:

```golang
type JsonIgnored struct {}

func (j *JsonIgnored) UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error {
  return nil
}

type Message struct {
  Ignored JsonIgnored`json:"e"`
  EventId int64      `json:"E"`
}
```