# How can I do marshal/unmarshal JSON in Go in a case sensitive way?

Tags: json, go

[Golang does not support case sensitive unmarshalling of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006073/json-unmarshal-struct-case-sensitively) using the standard packages. This seems like a very common need though.

Is there any way to get a precise matching of cases when marshalling and unmarshalling JSON?

Example: I don't want to match "id" with "ID".

Answer (score 2):

The standard library encoding/json does in fact support case sensitive encoding/decoding if your data structures define the members that way and include tags appropriately.

For example:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

type image struct {
  Url string `json:"url"`
}

type images struct {
  Image1 image `json:"image"`
  Image2 image `json:"Image"`
}

func main() {
  i := images{Image1: image{Url: "test.jpg"}, Image2: image{Url: "test2.jpg"}}

  data, err := json.Marshal(i)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %s", err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(data))

  var i2 images
  err = json.Unmarshal(data, &i2)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %s", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", i2)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/GWUWYUc-T9t

Which will output:

```
{"image":{"url":"test.jpg"},"Image":{"url":"test2.jpg"}}
main.images{Image1:main.image{Url:"test.jpg"}, Image2:main.image{Url:"test2.jpg"}}
```

However, another good json encoding package is jsonparser: https://github.com/buger/jsonparser

I don't know if it supports case sensativity differentaly then the standard library package.

Comment: "IMAGE" could still override one of those fields though: https://play.golang.org/p/QUu7sGsM61s. Order matters more than case, which is surprising.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works in your case, but for me the standard library does *not* respect case sensitivity. I've got a JSON which has just single letters as keys and it mixes for example a `A` with a `a` - and also throws error because one is a string and the other a number. The alternative library mentioned above (https://github.com/buger/jsonparser) solved my problem, thanks!